# Configure SMTP Service to deliver mails to SMTP Server

Tags: smtp

I've been having an issue configuring two servers for sending mails, the escenario is the following:

We have a SERVER A, it is a Windows Server 2003, it has installed SMTP Services, but it is not the server for mailing. It holds an .Net application called MAILER, which is configured to send mails to the default mail server on the organization (it's on a different server).

SERVER B, is the default mail server of the organization, it has Microsoft Exchange.

The issue is that when MAILER tries to send a mail, the message is being kept on the SERVER A on this folder C:\Inetpub\wwroot\SMTP\Queue... even when we already configured the STMP service on SERVER A (where the application MAILER resides) to DELIVER every mail to SERVER B.

I hope I made myself clear, and that you can help me configuring my SMTP service on server A.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should configure SmartHost on SERVER A SMTP service (find it into advanced properties of delivery section).

I am unable to give you precise informations because I haven't a Win2003 machine with SMTP service.